# TypeError: Module name, 'vue' does not resolve to a valid URL on GitHub Pages Deployment

Tags: vuejs3, vuex, github-pages

I’ve been working on a Vue.js project using Vite as my build tool, and everything works perfectly in the local development environment. However, when I deploy my project to GitHub Pages, I encounter the following error in the browser console:

```
TypeError: Module name, 'vue' does not resolve to a valid URL.
```

This error prevents my Vue app from rendering correctly, and I only see a blank page. Here’s some relevant information about my project setup:

```
•   Build Tool: Vite
•   Vue Version: 3.x
•   Deployment Platform: GitHub Pages
•   Project Structure: Standard Vue project structure generated by Vite
```

https://github.com/albim360/comfy-ecommerce

Change main.ts to main.js
change index.html configuration
change vite base path